# TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of undefined --- webpack in angular universal project

Tags: webpack, angular5, angular-universal

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of undefined --- webpack in angular universal project

when I bundle my project with webpack:

```
webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.universal.config.js.
```

webpack.universal.config.json

```
plugins: [ new AngularCompilerPlugin({ tsConfigPath: root('./src/tsconfig.server.json'), skipCodeGeneration: false})]
```

package.json

```
"@angular/typescript": "^2.0.0-5d0e199",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^1.10.2",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"normalize-port": "^1.0.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
"serialize-javascript": "^1.5.0",
"ts-loader": "^4.0.0",
"webpack": "^3.11.0",
```

is there someone saw this error before?

Comment: I finally find the solution... I have to install webpack-cli